# Добавление массива значений в одну колонку таблицы DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

Всем привет! Прошу помочь, что то не могу решить проблему. Суть вопроса.
Пишу метод. Принимаем в параметры таблицу dt, лист с номерами колонок которые нужно выбрать у таблицы dt и сформировав новую таблицу с выбранными нужными колонками вернуть.

```
 public DataTable TableFiltreToColl(DataTable dt, List<NumberColumn> list)
     {   
            DataTable resTable = new DataTable();

       // в листе нужно оставить только те колонки где номер колонки не равен -1
                var listTable = from lt in list
                    where lt.Number != -1
                    select lt;


 // Нужен массив с необходимыми нам колонками. "имя колонки" = 1
int quantityColl = dt.Columns.Count; //количество колонок
int coll;
string nameColl;

// нужно создать таблицу с нужными колонками. Колонки заданы в полученном листе.
// в ListTable содержится лист с название колонки и номер колонки в таблице dt
foreach (var li in listTable)
 {
    coll = li.Number;
    nameColl = li.Name;

   if (coll != -1) //Если колонка имеет значение -1, значит этой колонки в таблице не должно быть.
 {
   DataColumn nameColumn = new DataColumn(nameColl, 
              Type.GetType("System.String")); // Создали колонку таблицы
    resTable.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
  }

}    
// мы создали таблицу с нужными нам колонками. Теперь нужно записать данные в нужные колонки
// Таблица resTable содержит имена колонок таблицы такие же как и имена в листе ListTAble, но номера колонок уже свои 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...

string str;
int co;
DataRow dataRow = resTable.NewRow();   

 for (int i = 0; i < resTable.Columns.Count; i++)
 {
   str = resTable.Columns[i].ColumnName; // получаем имя колонки из 
   co = NumColl(str, list); // получаем номер колонки исходной таблицы с этим именем колонки

var collArray = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x.ItemArray[co]).ToArray(); //Получили массив одной колонки с номером co
!!!!!! ТУТ проблема!!!! Как в созданную таблицу поместить массив колонки collArray 

     dataRow.ItemArray[i] = new object[]{collArray};  

                    //for (int j = 0; j < collArray.Length; j++)
                    //{
                    //    dataRow[j] = collArray[j];
                    //    resTable.Rows.Add(dataRow[str]);
                    //}

                }
    }
return resTable;

        }
```

Comment: public int NumColl(string str, List<NumberColumn> numColumns)
        {
            int number = 0;
            var name = from n in numColumns
                where n.Name == str
                select n;
            foreach (NumberColumn nc in name)
            {
                number = nc.Number;

                // Console.WriteLine($"{nc.Number}");
            }

            return number;
        }

Comment: В `dataRow.ItemArray[i]` пишется одно значение. Не нужно туда массив присваивать. Ну... разве что переделать так  `xdataRow[j].ItemArray[i] = collArray[j]`.

Comment: Не уверен (лень код набивать), но может просто: `dataRow.ItemArray = collArray;` ?

Comment: Нет dataRow.ItemArray = collArray; так не проходит.

Comment: Дайте входные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то так:

```
public DataTable FilterTable(DataTable dt, List<NumberColumn> list)
{
    var resTable = new DataTable();

    foreach (var nc in list.Where(x => x.Number != -1))
    {
        resTable.Columns.Add(nc.Name, typeof(string));
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var newRow = resTable.NewRow();
        foreach (DataColumn column in resTable.Columns)
        {
            newRow[column.ColumnName] = row[column.ColumnName];
        }
        resTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    return resTable;
}
```

---

Немного критики.

У вас в коде фигурирует класс `NumberColumn`, который содержит свойства `Number` и `Name`. Имхо, его следует переименовать. Например, назвать `ColumnInfo`.

---

По-моему, код можно упростить до следующего:

```
var columnNames = list.Where(x => x.Number != -1).Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
var resTable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(false, columnNames);
```

Если бы вы предоставили код, создающий и наполняющий данными исходный DataTable и список колонок для копирования, то я бы потестил и написал выверенный код.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ! Проверяю работу выскакивает ошибка System.ArgumentException: "Столбец "Names" не принадлежит таблице Table."

Comment: public DataTable FilterTable(DataTable dt, List<NumberColumn> list)
{
    var resTable = new DataTable();

    foreach (var nc in list.Where(x => x.Number != -1))
    {
        resTable.Columns.Add(nc.Name, typeof(string));
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var newRow = resTable.NewRow();
        foreach (DataColumn column in resTable.Columns)
        {
            newRow[column.ColumnName] = row[column.ColumnName]; !!!! В этом месте ошибка!!!
        }
        resTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }

    return resTable;
}

Comment: @ИгорьАлексеенко - _Если бы вы предоставили код, создающий и наполняющий данными..._

Comment: Критика принимается.

Comment: Если бы вы предоставили код, создающий и наполняющий данными исходный DataTable и список колонок для копирования, то я бы потестил и написал выверенный код.  Код наполняющий dt  - это считанная таблица из Excel файла. Другими словами вся таблица. Из этой таблицы нужно выбрать только те колонки которые указал пользователь, они в List-е имеют значение и не ровны -1.

Comment: Другими словами в метод мы получаем таблицу из которой нужно сформировать таблицу с нужными нам колонками.

Comment: @ИгорьАлексеенко - Приведенный код именно это и делает - формирует таблицу с нужными колонками и копирует данные.

Comment: @ИгорьАлексеенко - так вы покажете _данные_, которые у вас реально имеются? Мне-то не видно, что там в Excel.

Comment: @ИгорьАлексеенко - _Столбец "Names" не принадлежит таблице Table_ - а зачем вы заносите туда столбец, которого нет на самом деле? В конце концов, добавьте проверку (`if`, `Contains`).

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодиться. Решение ниже. Может у кого есть проще решение, пишите.

```
public string GetDataRow(int n, int s, DataTable dt)
    {

        var rowN = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x.ItemArray[n]).ToArray(); 
        string str = rowN[s].ToString(); 
        return str;

    }


    public DataTable FilterTable(DataTable dt, List<ColumnInfo> list)
    {
        var resTable = new DataTable(); //Создаем таблицу

        foreach (var nc in list.Where(x => x.Number != -1))   
        {
            resTable.Columns.Add(nc.Name, typeof(string));
        }

        var columnNames = list.Where(x => x.Number != -1).Select(x => x.Name).ToArray(); 


        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
        {
            DataRow dataRow = resTable.NewRow();

            foreach (var cn in columnNames) 
            {
                int n = NumColl(cn, list); 

               dataRow[cn] = GetDataRow( n, i, dt); 

            }
            resTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);  

        }

        return resTable;
    }
```

```
public int NumColl(string str, List<ColumnInfo> numColumns)
        {
            int number = 0;
            var name = from n in numColumns
                where n.Name == str
                select n;
            foreach (ColumnInfo nc in name)
            {
                number = nc.Number;

               // Console.WriteLine($"{nc.Number}");
            }

            return number;
        }
```